# Maximal subtrees of connected graph

Tags: graph-theory

Are all maximal subtrees of a simple connected graph isomorphic?
any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is a resounding "No". Even as small as the complete graph on four vertices, one can find nonisomorphic spanning trees.

[image]
[image]

The number of nonisomorphic trees grows reasonably quickly after that. For example, the complete graph on ten vertices has 106 nonisomorphic spanning trees.

(Incidentally, here is a [small collection of spanning trees](http://austinmohr.com/work/trees/) you might find interesting.)

Comment: Thanks, a lot, for the link too, it seems interesting. I will have a look